# configuring an associated type of a pallet to a pallet

Tags: frame

To what will the `Currency` associated type of `pallet-assets` be configured if I configure it to `pallet-balances` like done in [statemint](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/aae4731d38160d4da47205ea5b275d0481ef70eb/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemint/src/lib.rs#L255)?

- Will it be set to something within `pallet-balances`, what exactly?
- Or to the entire pallet, how does this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the whole pallet will become a struct by the macros, thats why when you see Currency=Balances it works

Comment: check this for an example: https://docs.substrate.io/build/pallet-coupling/ and this to understand the effect of the various macros: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/frame-macros/

Comment: Alright this gives me a direction to dig into, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Balances` being the name that is set for `pallet-balances` in `construct_runtime!`. This is a type declaration that looks like:

```
type Balances = pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>;
```

> Or to the entire pallet, how does this work?

So, this is right. `Currency` is a trait and [this trait is implemented for the `pallet_balances::Pallet`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7ff6fa2bfa47f288216fdc6e1585f69756c5ec75/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1408). So, `pallet-assets` will use `pallet-balances` as currency implementation through the `Currency` trait.

Comment: But how is the `Currency` associated type of `pallet-assets` then linked to the `Currency` trait?

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cba59778aa5207b11f7513e5cbb127ea47dd8924/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L257 this requires that `Currency` implements `ReservableCurrency` and `ReservableCurrency` requires that any type that implements this trait also implements `Currency`: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cba59778aa5207b11f7513e5cbb127ea47dd8924/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/currency/reservable.rs#L30

( this is called super trait)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!